# Subtracting Values from Two Datasets in Single Table

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reporting

I'm trying to basically subtract time to get the time difference in SSRS to take out total working hours. However, I'm getting error **"An unexpected error occurred while compiling expressions. Native compiler return value: '[BC30025] Property missing 'End Property'.'."** from the available solutions in here or over the internet.
I tried to use lookup as well: ***=Lookup(Fields!Date.Value & Fields!Employee_Name.Value, Fields!Date.Value & Fields!Name_or_title.Value, Fields!Check_Out_Time.Value, "DataSet2") - (Fields!Check_In_Time.Value)*** which shows error as [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuHur.png)
Can someone guide me how to get time difference from two different datasets please? I'm new to SSRSSQL

Comment: A few things you will need to change. If Fields!Date.Value is actually a date or date/time then you will need to convert it to a string before you can concatenate it with the employee name. Then if `Check_In_Time` and `Check_Out_Time` are datetimes, then you need to use `DateDiff()` rather than simply subtracting one from the other.

Comment: Thank you, however, I sort it out like this "=Hour(Lookup(Fields!Date.Value & Fields!Employee_Name.Value, Fields!Date.Value & Fields!Name_or_title.Value, Fields!Check_Out_Time.Value, "DataSet2")) - Hour(Fields!Check_In_Time.Value)" and it worked